# How to replace or add large view in Layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablelayout

I created custom number keyboard with TableLayout successfully.[image: This is resut]

This is source

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:clickable="true">



<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/keyboard_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#e5e5e5" />


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
            android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size_medium_large"
            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#e5e5e5" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_two"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
            android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size_medium_large"

            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#e5e5e5" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_three"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
            android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size_medium_large"

            />

    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#e5e5e5" />


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_four"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
            android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size_medium_large"


            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#e5e5e5" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_five"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
            android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size_medium_large"


            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#e5e5e5" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_six"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="6"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
            android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size_medium_large"


            />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#e5e5e5" />


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_seven"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="7"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
            android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size_medium_large"

            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#e5e5e5" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_eight"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="8"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
            android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size_medium_large"


            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#e5e5e5" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_nine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="9"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
            android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size_medium_large"


            />

    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#e5e5e5" />


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/keyboard_dot"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="."
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size_medium_large"

                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/keyboard_left"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_fingerprint_white"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#e5e5e5" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_zero"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
            android:textSize="@dimen/u_common_text_size_medium_large"

            />


        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#e5e5e5" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/keyboard_right"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I created fragment and replaced this fragment in layout like this

```
 public static void replace(FragmentManager fm, Fragment fragment, int container) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(container, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

I have one problem.My replace function freezing screen in some devices.
My question is  that is it a correct solution? how i can solve my problem? 
p.s
My main class also is Fragment,not Activity

Comment: Did you create fragment only 1 time or every time you replace? Better way is make it extends a View, not with Fragment.

Comment: u can add the full layout inside <include> tag in your parent layout and hide it's visibility on or off everytime

Comment: I tried it also,but same problem.In my case,when layout where i try to replace my keyboard fragmen are invisible and in button click ,i try to visible with top_up andrimation @ rafsanahmad007

Comment: I replaced fragment only first time.what do you mean? can you explain more ?@TruongHieu

Comment: I mean you should replace only 1 time, then use visibility to show up or hide.